# How to add a new row into the output of Panda describe function output in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Here is my Python question:

I am asked to generate an output table which contains the number of Nan in each variables (there are more than 10 variables in the data), min, max, mean, std, 25%, 50%,and 70%. I used the describe function in panda to created the describe table which gave me everything i want but the number of Nan in each variables. I am thinking about adding the number of Nan as a new row into the output generated from the describe output.

Anyone can help with this?

```
output = input_data.describe(include=[np.number]) # this gives the table output

count_nan = input_data.isnull().sum(axis=0) # this counts the number of Nan of each variable
```

How can I add the second as a row into the first table?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to append a new row to a DataFrame:

```
In [21]: output.append(pd.Series(count_nan, name='nans'))
Out[21]: 
              0         1         2         3         4
count  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000  4.000000
mean   0.583707  0.578610  0.566523  0.480307  0.540259
std    0.142930  0.358793  0.309701  0.097326  0.277490
min    0.450488  0.123328  0.151346  0.381263  0.226411
25%    0.519591  0.406628  0.478343  0.406436  0.429003
50%    0.549012  0.610845  0.607350  0.478787  0.516508
75%    0.613127  0.782827  0.695530  0.552658  0.627764
max    0.786316  0.969421  0.900046  0.582391  0.901610
nans   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```